# Macro to Check column of Values, then render items into different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet1 that looks like:

```
 ITEM      QTY
======     ===
"ITEM1"     2
"ITEM2"     0
"ITEM3"     1
"ITEM4"     0
```

And I have another sheet2 where I'd like it to check to see if the item in this table has a quantity greater than zero, and if so, write to a new table in sheet 2 thus:

```
 ITEM      QTY
======     ===
"ITEM1"     2
"ITEM3"     1
```

I would know how to do this an other language, like ruby, but I don't really know VBA that well. Was hoping someone could help me out. I'm thinking, that in pseudocode, it would look something like

```
SheetCounter=1
SelectSheet1
  for(x=1, x < column-height, x++)
    if(item-x.qty > 0)
      copy item.x.title to sheet2, cell $A$SheetCounter
      copy item.x.qty to sheet2, cell $B$SheetCounter
      SheetCounter++
      x++
    else
      x++
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cdest As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set cdest = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            c.Resize(1, 2).Copy cdest
            Set cdest = cdest.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```